# JTable sorting randomly

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

I'm trying to sort my table by number, but it gets like this

After creating:

[[image: After creating]]

After clicking on "№" once

[[image: After clicking on "№" once]]

How to fix it and get from 14 to 0 and from 0 to 14 only?
Thank you!

Comment: We cannot help you if you do not include the source code.  Please read [ask].

Comment: From the looks of it, they are being sorted as strings and not integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add `Integer` objects to the `TableModel`, not Strings representing integers.
2. Override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of the `TableModel` to return `Integer.class` for the first column.

Then the table will use an Integer Comparator to sort the first column.